# How to get the required data when the payload after the all component is of CopyOnWriteArrayList<Object> type?

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-component

Currently I m working on Mule 3.4.2 EE. I have one doubt regarding Mule All coponent. In all block iam calling two flow refs to get the data and after the mule all component is of type `CopyOnWriteArrayList<Object>` How can i get the data?? Thanks in advance.

```
<sub-flow name="Aggregating_Flow" doc:name="Aggregating_Flow">
        <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
        <all doc:name="All">
            <flow-ref name="PHYBMDATAReportingDataFetchFlow" doc:name="PHYBMDATAReportingDataFetchFlow"/>
            <flow-ref name="PHYBMDATABOALFReportingDataFetchFlow" doc:name="PHYBMDATABOALFReportingDataFetchFlow"/>
        </all>
        <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" message="paaaaaayload is #[payload:]"/>
        <component class="com.xxx.bmrs.api.util.PrepareBMRSPHYBMDATAXMLResponse" doc:name="PrepareBMRSPHYBMDATAXMLResponse"/>
        <logger  level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
    </sub-flow>
```

after the all coponent i m using java component. How can i get the data i m getting the following exception..

```
********************************************************************************
Message               : Payload was invalidated calling setPayload and the message is not collection anymore. (java.lang.IllegalStateException). Message payload is of type: PHYBMDATARequest
Code                  : MULE_ERROR--2
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Exception stack is:
1. Payload was invalidated calling setPayload and the message is not collection anymore. (java.lang.IllegalStateException)
  org.mule.DefaultMessageCollection:104 (null)
2. Payload was invalidated calling setPayload and the message is not collection anymore. (java.lang.IllegalStateException). Message payload is of type: PHYBMDATARequest (org.mule.api.MessagingException)
  org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor:32 (http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/api/MessagingException.html)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Root Exception stack trace:
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Payload was invalidated calling setPayload and the message is not collection anymore.
    at org.mule.DefaultMessageCollection.checkValidPayload(DefaultMessageCollection.java:104)
    at org.mule.DefaultMessageCollection.newThreadCopy(DefaultMessageCollection.java:309)
    at org.mule.DefaultMuleEvent.newThreadCopy(DefaultMuleEvent.java:799)
    + 3 more (set debug level logging or '-Dmule.verbose.exceptions=true' for everything)
********************************************************************************
```

Answer (score 0):

See this bug here: https://www.mulesoft.org/jira/browse/MULE-6795

You can add a `combine-collections-transformer` after the all router.

Or better yet change your `all` router to `scatter-gather` if you can: http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Scatter-Gather